# Explanation of Settings > Apps and internal vs external storage (Android 4.1)

Tags: settings, storage, app2sd

Can anyone please provide a clear explanation of the different information displayed in the Apps section of Android Settigs? Precisely:

### Apps List

[image]

1. **The ON SD CARD tab.** Does it show apps that are *installed* on the SD card, or any app that has *some data* stored on the external storage, even though the app itself may be installed internally?
2. **The checkboxes.** Does it indicate that this app is actually *installed* on the external  storage? Implying that the unchecked apps are installed internally, but have some data stored on the SD card?
3. **The size in MB.** Is this the total amount of data this app has stored on the SD card, *including the app "executable" itself*, in case the app is also *installed* on external storage?

### App Details

[image]

4. **The 'Move' button.** It offers either a) `Move to Internal Storage` or b) `Move to Data Storage`. Is this a reliable indication of where the app is currently *installed*? I.E. when it offers to `Move to Internal Storage`, is it safe to assume that the app is *installed on external*? Or does it say nothing about where the app executable is located, and is only offering me to move *any app-related files* to the internal memory? Is *data storage* synonymous to *external storage* ?
5. **What do the different sizes mean?** I mean `App`, `USB storage app`, `Data`, `SD card`.

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes their time to try and clarify this to me!